# How can I automatically trigger an item?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this code:

```
action = QAction("Always On Top", mw)
action.setCheckable(True)
action.triggered.connect(alwaysOnTop)
mw.form.menuTools.addAction(action)
```

This basically creates a checkable menu item that runs the function `alwaysOnTop` whenever I click it. My question is, is there a way to automatically trigger this item?

I've tried `action.setCheckable(True)` but this only change the GUI and doesn't really trigger the function (it only changes the state of the checkable). And no, unfortunately I can't just call the `alwaysOnTop` function. I need to find a way to specifically trigger the menu item with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`triggered` is a PyQt or PySide signal, depending on what binder you're using. You can emit it programmatically as:

```
action.triggered.emit(val)
```

The `val` depends on how you have managed your `alwaysOnTop` slot. `triggered` should be bound to a slot accepting a bool paramter indicating whether the action has been checked or unchecked.

Comment: Terrific. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that, for consistency, the action should be also checked/unchecked (otherwise it will keep the current state, since `triggered` doesn't change it). Another possibility is to connect to the `toggled` signal, instead.

Comment: As per the doc (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) `triggered` and `toggled` are two slightly different signals. I think the most appreciable difference comes up when an action is not checkable, that is not this case. However, stuck to its request, `triggered` is the right signal. While, if `toggle` could be used, the `setChecked(True)` method would be enough.